# Yii framework: Controller/Action url & parameters

Tags: php, url, path, yii

In my application , I have `ApiController` with `actionUsers`, So in YII the path becomes `api/users`. Now in order to get certain users info , I use the following path `api/users/id/10` where 10 is the userID and `id` part of the path is basically a GET parameter (`api/users?id=10`).

Is there any way to do the same thing without `id` part of the path, i.e. I want my path to look like `api/users/10`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're going to need to put in rule patterns in the urlManager component:

[Yii Framework Documentation: url](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/topics.url)

Your config should look something like this:

```
array(
    ......
    'components'=>array(
        ......
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                'api/users/<id>'=>'api/users',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

You can then get the  value by:

```
$id = Yii::app()->getRequest()->getQuery('id');
```

Comment: It's a shame that Yii doesn't do this mapping for you implicitly. For 95% of cases, /users/view/1/ should go to UserController::view($id) without you having to instruct Yii to make this connection.

Answer (score 3):

Try This......

```
$id = Yii::app()->request->getParam('id');
```

Comment: can it be done like if user pass id then also it should go to the action and if not then also in the same action?

Answer (score 0):

in addition to @shiki's answer you can also do this

```
array(
    ......
    'components'=>array(
        ......
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                'api/users/<id>'=>'api/users',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

and in action

```
public function actionUsers($id=null)  // argument variable should same as in urlmanager
    {
     echo $id;
    }
```