# Yii: how to format url so that the controller id is not shown

Tags: php, yii

Is it possible to hide the controller id in the URL through urlManager.

e.g. url http://mysite.com/controller/action

shall show up as

http://mystite.com/action

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should be possible by creating a custom format (see [HERE](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url)):

```
array(
  'action'=>'controller/action',
  'action/<id:\d+>'=>'controller/action',
)
```

Comment: thanks, I did what you suggested and changed the config/apache config to not show index.php
The problem now is that I cannot access the pages and can only see the default yii successful install page when I goto mysite.com

All others routes e.g. mysite.com/stories/new don't work. below is the urlmanager config.

urlManager'=>array(
   'urlFormat'=>'path',
   'rules'=>array(
     'news'=>'stories/new',     
   ),
   'showScriptName'=>false,
   'caseSensitive'=>false,
  ),

Comment: resloved, here is another link to another post at Stackoverflow with similar question. Including it here as it was helpful.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2786723/1027798