# How to store the last value in my url into a variable in php?

Tags: php, yii

I have an example link here:

```
http://mydomain.com/myapp1/index.php/image/index/album/check+picture/id/1
```

Now I'm trying to retrieve the "1" at the very end of the url.

So far, I've tried the following code:

```
 $id = $_GET['id'];
```

But it is not working. I was used to the url having the `index.php?id=1` Syntax but I'm not entirely sure how to get this one working.

**UPDATE**

Before accepting an answer, I wanted to add this script I used to get the entire URL of the current page:

```
 $protocol = strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']),'https') === FALSE ? 'http' : 'https';
    $host     = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $script   = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    $params   = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    $currentUrl = $protocol . '://' . $host . $script . '?' . $params;

    echo $currentUrl;
```

When it echoes, it only prints out:

http://www.mydomain.com/myapp1/index.php?

Comment: Are you using any framework ? This is called pretty urls.

Comment: Yes, @Rikesh. I'm using Yii Framework

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yii framework: Controller/Action url & parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760869/yii-framework-controller-action-url-parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this :

```
echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: please check my revised question

Comment: @user3278616 - and you look at mine

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
$id = substr($url, strrpos( $url, '/' )+1);
```

Comment: Even if the $url is not part of the script anymore? 

I mean, I created a link from a previous page to redirect it to the link above.

Comment: please check my revised question

Answer (score -1):

Get YII Documentation...

```
$id = Yii::app()->request->getQuery('id')
```

Or

```
$id = Yii::app()->getRequest()->getQuery('id');
```

Possible duplicate

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760869/yii-framework-controller-action-url-parameters
```

Answer (score -2):

try this....

```
$url = "http://mydomain.com/myapp1/index.php/image/index/album/check+picture/id/1";

$value = substr(strrchr(rtrim($url, '/'), '/'), 1);
```

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076263/get-the-value-of-a-url-after-the-last-slash)

In Yii Framework you can get value like this...

```
$id = Yii::app()->getRequest()->getQuery('id');
```

OR

```
$id = Yii::app()->request->getParam('id');
```

Comment: please check my revised question

Comment: @user3278616 I revised my answer according to Yii.